# Link_to helper method to include icon within a element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Here's what the default scaffolding generates:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', admin_user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete?' } %>
```

I want to create a helper method so that I can call a `remove_link(admin_user)` and have it behave the same way:

```
  def remove_link(item)    
    link_to item, method: :delete, :data { confirm: 'Esta seguro que quiere eliminar este registro?' } do
      "#{content_tag :i, nil, class: 'icon-remove-sign'}".html_safe
    end
  end
```

But I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError in Admin::UsersController#index

```
/home/sergio/Work/foo/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting tASSOC
... item, method: :delete, :data { confirm: 'Esta seguro que qu...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the third argument to `link_to`, you can use `data: foo` or `:data => foo`, but not `:data foo`

```
link_to item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Esta seguro que quiere eliminar este registro?' } do
```